# BBedit find line and remove caracter

Tags: bbedit, find-replace

I have multiple text files with same structure. I want to remove "." in the second line only
ID 330.22 by ID 33022
The number of digits could change (other examples 234567.33 or 34.3)

GENE

ID 330.22

INFO1 44.2

INFO2 22.3"

Answer (score 1):

- Do a Search -> Multi-File Search, and make sure Grep is turned on.
- Select the checkbox in front of the group of documents you want to do this on (this is easy if you have all the files in a single project, then you can just select the project).
- Use this as your search pattern: `^ID (.*)\.(.*)$`
- Use this as your replace pattern: `ID \1\2`
- Replace All

[image: Screenshot of the above instructions]